# Django Difficult! : 'Account' object has no attribute 'has_perms'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
AttributeError at /HomeFeed/blog/1/testuser1-2/member-list/
'Account' object has no attribute 'has_perms'
```

Hi, tbh I'm not even sure whats causing the error. After some research I realised it might have something to do with `AbstractBaseUser`, but I'm unsure of what exactly is causing it.

Basically I'm trying to direct to a list of members in the blog post. Theres should be nothing wrong with my template. The error is either with my **views** or my **models**. Let me know if you need additional information...

**views.py**

```
class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post=self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        return context

class MemberListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, BlogPostMixin, DetailView):    
    template_name = "HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html"
    permission_required = ('blogpost.view_all_blogpost_members',)
```

**detail_blog.html**

```
<a href='{% url "HomeFeed:member_list" blog_post.pk blog_post.slug %}'>View my blog's members list</a>
```

**models.py**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_activ = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   objects = MyAccountManager()
 
   #For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin

class BlogPost(models.Model):
   chief_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, 
   blank=False, unique=True)
   brief_description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
   body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
   members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="members")
```

**urls.py**

```
path("blog/<pk>/<slug>/member-list/", MemberListView.as_view(), name="member_list"), 
path('<slug>/detail/', DetailBlogPostView.as_view(), name= "detail"),
path('<user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
```

***Traceback:***

```
Internal Server Error: /HomeFeed/blog/1/testuser1-2/member-list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 83, in dispatch
    if not self.has_permission():
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 80, in has_permission
    return self.request.user.has_perms(perms)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 257, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'has_perms'
```

Comment: you have defined only has_perm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views, simply remove `PermissionRequiredMixin` and it will work